# Whatsapp FFMPEG thumbnail is not showing

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, ffmpeg, command-line-interface, whatsapp

I want to run a command that will add an image as a thumbnail to a video. The video will be shared by WhatsApp with a thumbnail showing up.

The problem is that after running the following command thumbnails don't show up in Whatsapp though it shows on Windows 10.

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/Video.mp4 -i path/to/Video.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic -strict -2 path/to/out.mp4
```

And another problem is that the video with a thumbnail doesn't play on Android, iPhone, Windows, nor on Linux.

**Log:**

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1+rpt1~deb10u1 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[libaom-av1 @ 0x5b7130] v1.0.0
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6av01mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:03:30.70, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 213 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 256x144, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.627000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.701000000
Input #1, image2, from 'Video.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23403 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mp4 @ 0x625260] track 2: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6av01mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Video: av1 (Main) (av01 / 0x31307661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 256x144, q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.627000000
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: opus (Opus / 0x7375704F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.701000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 q=-1.0 size=    3840kB time=00:02:47.56 bitrate= 187.frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 size=    5632kB time=00:03:30.68 bitrate= 219.0kbits/s speed= 324x    
video:2275kB audio:3221kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.464468%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: It's okay if it works with python.

Comment: Show the full log.

Comment: Does the original input work in WhatsApp, Facebook, etc? It is AV1 video with Opus audio in MP4. Those are new video and audio formats, so support may be limited. You should refer to the help of each service to see if they support AV1 and Opus in MP4.

Comment: @llogando do you suggest any specific audio type? For example: 'm4a' or 'mp3' etc.

Comment: AAC is widely accepted and the most common format in MP4, but if your targets support Opus then use it instead as it is very efficient and you can avoid re-encoding (if all of your inputs are already Opus).

Comment: Well, I can't get the audio format in AAC but I can convert it to M4A, as a result, a black thumbnail showed in WhatsApp, therefore, there is an improvement. Anyways I will try to convert the audio extension to AAC and see what will happen. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I was referring to the format of the audio stream (Opus, AAC), not the container format or the extension (`.mp4`, `.m4a`, `.aac`).

Comment: Actually the video can not be downloaded containing AAC audio so I downloaded it in M4A audio extension. I do not think I have got it. I will search for a command that converts the inner audio extension of a video to AAC and test it back. I do not know if that will work. I might have to extract the video and the audio alone then merge them together after conversion. What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202171/discussion-between-youssof-h-and-llogan).

Comment: You never answered my question if your targets accept your original AV1+Opus in MP4 video.

Comment: @llogan I do not know if AV1 is supported but for sure that Opus is not supported, but actually AAC works great as an audio system which allows the video to show a thumbnail as the first frame of the video. Therefore I thought of adding a frame at the beginning of the video as the thumbnail image.

Comment: Then add `-c:a aac` (after `-c copy`) and test.

Comment: You need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before `-c copy` then the video will work on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that when I transcode the videos to 30 fps, then I get a preview in WhatsApp.
Maybe this helps.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? How exactly shoudl the provided information help?

Comment: I was converting a video to 5 fps using ffmpeg. Trying to decrease the size of the video as there were only images in the video. Facing the same issue of black thumbnail i up'ed the frames to 10 fps and it is working fine now.